# Datetime capitalize month

Tags: languages, capitalization, datetime

I'm using the `datetime` package. How could I have a date format with the month name in capital letters?

```
\usepackage{datetime}
% some code here
\newdateformat{mifecha}{Bilbao, a \THEDAY~de \monthname[\THEMONTH] de \THEYEAR}
\mifecha\date{\today}
```

Gives me:

> Bilbao, a 15 de noviembre de 2013

But I would like:

> Bilbao, a 15 de Noviembre de 2013

I have tried the command `\capitalisewords` without success, but maybe it's because I should use a combination of `\expandafter` commands or something related.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), since the default output seems to be capitalized. I assume you're using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` as well?

Comment: If you're writing the document in Spanish is incorrect to write the months starting capitalized. http://rae.es/consultas/mayuscula-o-minuscula-en-los-meses-los-dias-de-la-semana-y-las-estaciones-del-ano

Comment: @osjerick you're right, thanks for the correction, RAE after all dictates the norms in Spanish. However, if you see motivation letters you will see that putting the month in capital letters is a generalised error due to the English influence as it's also noted here: http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/forma-de-poner-la-fecha-5224/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're loading [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) with the `spanish` option, then your months will start in lowercase as this is the definition enforced by `babel`. A redefinition of `\monthnamespanish` corrects this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage{datetime}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime
\newdateformat{mifecha}{Bilbao, a \THEDAY~de \monthname[\THEMONTH] de \THEYEAR}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\monthnamespanish}[1][\month]{%
  \@orgargctr=#1\relax
  \ifcase\@orgargctr
    \PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
      Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
    \or Enero%
    \or Febrero%
    \or Marzo%
    \or Abril%
    \or Mayo%
    \or Junio%
    \or Julio%
    \or Agosto%
    \or Septiembre%
    \or Octubre%
    \or Noviembre%
    \or Diciembre%
    \else \PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
      Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mifecha\today
\end{document}
```

You may also be interested in updating `\dayofweeknameidspanish` and `\shortdayofweeknameidspanish`.

Comment: I'm not using babel but the polyglossia package, as I'm using XeLaTeX, however I works perfectly with polyglossia too ^^V

Comment: I needed to capitalize the month but only in one occurrence (an only Month-Year date starting the sentence). So I have used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145698/26430) with the spanish names capitalized.