# display custom date with custom date format with datetime package

Tags: datetime

using 'datetime' package, one can produce a custom date with custom date format like this:

```
\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{nwfmt}{\the\day, \THEDAY \monthday, \THEYEAR}
\newdate{mydate}{21}{12}{2020}

\begin{document}
\nwfmt
\mydate

\end{document}
```

but this does not give what i want. I want something like this:
"monday, 21 december, 2020", i.e. full name of day and month and no uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

The `\DayName` from `scrdate` could be easily converted to lowercase, but the `\monthname` had to be explicitly defined (anglicizing [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145108/146828)).  That's the best solution I could get for a complete lower-case date, looking like:

[image: Lower-case date]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{datetime, scrdate}

\newdateformat{nwfmt}{\MakeLowercase{\DayName{\THEYEAR}{\THEMONTH}{\THEDAY}},
                      \THEDAY\ \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\monthname}[1][\month]{%
  \@orgargctr=#1\relax
  \ifcase\@orgargctr
    \PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
      Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
    \or january%
    \or february%
    \or march%
    \or april%
    \or may%
    \or june%
    \or july%
    \or august%
    \or september%
    \or october%
    \or november%
    \or december%
    \else \PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
      Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newdate{mydate}{21}{12}{2020}

\begin{document}

\nwfmt\displaydate{mydate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i also want the ^st, ^nd, ^rd, ^th

Comment: Your solution lies on page 8-9 of the `datetime` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/datetime.pdf).  BTW: There is a way of expressing appreciation to answers you find useful by upvoting or accepting them... I hope you are aware of that !

Comment: i'll do that in a later time